# spaCy version 3 cannot add 'negative' example, how can I resolve?

Tags: python, machine-learning, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3, spacy-transformers

In spaCy 3, we now train our model with the configuration system, and we need to use `DocBin.to_disk("any_name.spacy")` to export the training data.

The problem is, we need to first create `Span` objects to store the entites in the text, and then assign them to doc.ents. During this process, if there are no entities marked in the text, `doc.char_span(0,0,"LABEL")` (0,0, because there is no entity) will return `None`, and this cannot be appended into the DocBin.

In simple terms, I cannot add any negative examples into my training data. Have anyone figure out a way to add negative example into their data?

I tried `doc.char_span(0,0,"NO_ENTITY")` as a place holder and see if it returns a span as `""`, not it doesn't work.

Comment: If there are no entities in a document you don't need to add an empty span, you can just save the doc with no entities. Is there a reason you aren't doing that?